# panning and viewing a javascript view in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, html

this is bit of a tricky one for me to explain, so will try my best..

If you go to the below link, you will see I am loading up a 'geo Map' type view using javascript. (all code should be available via the sourecode, I was unable to share via JSFiddle)

[Map Demo](http://simonarcher.me/demo/)

What I'm trying to accomplish, is for this view to be full height on a mobile device, and able to pan left and right across the map.

Currently, viewing the map on a mobile device (ie, an iPhone), you see a portion of the map, which is fine, but you're unable to pan. It has like a rubber band effect. I noticed that you can pan once zooming, but otherwise im struggling.

What is the best way to get the view to appear in full height, and be able to pan across the width on a mobile device?

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance for any advice and suggestions!